# Is there a way to check how many times a variable appears in a range in ti-basic? (For a factor calculator)

Tags: ti-basic

This is the section that has the problem, I don’t change N.`Input(“Enter number”, N)
...
For(i, 1, N+1)
Disp i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not. This is an in operator, but ti-basic does not have one.

Answer (score 1):

There is not, it doesn’t have an operator to do that.